# Unexpected behavior after zooming into a 3D object with OrbitControls + Three.js

Tags: camera, three.js

So, I have [this code](http://pastebin.com/PC5HJGBP). It's a small 3D scene with a ground, a red box, a custom loaded building and a rotating "sun". I'm delegating camera navigation to OrbitControls script, as it fits the most the way I want the camera to behave, however, there is a little weird problem: after I zoom in into a 3D object within this scene, rotate a little, then zoom out to "leave" the object, the zoom out process takes a billion scrolls. It's a weird behavior and I'm sorry if I'm not clear enough; once I'm in I have to scroll like forever, and every frame it seems to move "out of" the object very slowly, like the camera state is somehow screwed up.

I'm sorry if this very question has been already asked, I looked for this issue and tried stuff from other topics that **seemed** the same, but it didn't work.

@Edit
Wow, something even weirder. I tested zooming in [this example](http://threejs.org/examples/#misc_controls_orbit), indefinitely, then the zoom in started to grow VERY slowly (just like in my code). Am I misunderstanding something? It looks as if the amount of zoom-in's somehow blocked rendering or something.

Comment: 1. What version of three.js are you using? 2. Is `OrbitControls` from the same release? 3. You do not need to call `controls.update()` in your use case. 4. Try `controls.minDistance = 10;`

Comment: Thank you so much for stopping by. :)

1. Version r71; 2. Same from https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js; 3. Removed it now; 4. Just did.

Result: It seems to block viewing distance, but depending from what angle I'm closing into the object it still "enters" the object, and the same issue can be reproduced. Sometimes it blocks the camera (which is awesome, was going to look for that), and sometimes it allows the camera to go through either the BoxGeometry (red box) or pre-loaded building.

Comment: The camera will always pass through objects, unless you write code to prevent it.

Comment: Yes, that part is understandable, but the slow zoom in/out persists.

Comment: I am unable to duplicate that behavior if `minDistance` is set to a reasonable value.

Comment: Typo on my part, sorry. On a different note, if I am to collide the camera with the scene, is the most logical approach to edit OrbitControls and add raycasting there, or is it possible to do that without messing camera movement?

Comment: That is a decision you will have to make.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WestLangley tip actually solved my problem. Setting minDistance prevented the camera to zoom in infinitely, despite the actual rendering only showing a small step into the scene.